# Firebase Rest Sign In Error Structure

Tags: c#, .net, rest, firebase

When handling a login error I get this structure back.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_PASSWORD"
  }
}
```

I can de-serialize it into an anonymous class.

```
var errorData = new { error = new { code = 0, message = "errorid" } };
```

Or into a custom class.

```
public class Inner
{
    public string domain;
    public string reason;
    public string message;
}
public class Outer
{
    public List<Inner> errors;
    public int code;
    public string message;
}
public class FirebaseResponse
{
    public Outer error;
}
```

Is there a existing framework class I can de-serialize this too?
Is this just an HttpException or something? Or a custom response that I need to define just to access message.

Thanks.

Comment: go to this site and paste your json into the form on the page to generate the C# class for you 
http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: dynamic error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(content);